# Typescript error in ngrx/effects: computed property name must refer to a built in symbol

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am working with ngrx to implement an app state in my ionic 3.9.2 app (using this tutorial for guidance: https://gonehybrid.com/a-beginners-guide-to-using-ngrx-in-an-ionic-2-app-part-1/)

I am currently receiving this error when I try to run the app:

```
typescript: ...foo/bar/node_modules/@ngrx/effects/src/on_run_effects.d.ts, line: 9
A computed property name in a type literal must directly refer to a built-in symbol.
```

The error is in reference to the following code block:

```
export declare function isOnRunEffects(sourceInstance: {
    [onRunEffectsKey]?: onRunEffectsFn;
}): sourceInstance is OnRunEffects;
```

I am using ngrx effects version 6.1.0.

Any and all help is appreciated, as I am admittedly quite stumped by this. Thanks.

**EDIT**

I am using typescript version 3.0.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the error message, it looks like you're using a TypeScript version older than 2.7.  Please upgrade to 2.7 or newer, which [has new rules](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#constant-named-properties).

Comment: I am using typescript version 3.0.1, I will update the question to reflect this

Comment: The error text you are getting doesn't exist in TypeScript 3.0.1.  Somewhere you must be using an older version.  How are you running the app?

Comment: You're right! My local typescript version was 2.6.2, and upgrading it fixed the problem. Thank you very much!